# DirectoryScanner: getExcludedFiles performance issue using ant fileset

Tags: java, ant, fileset

Is there a way to speed up the performance of getExcludedFiles()? I've been play around with the fileset patterns, but could not get any improvement.

Here is my situation:

I have a fileset defined with these patterns:

```
basedir/normal/abc/control/*.ins
basedir/normal/abc/models/bx/cells/*.l
```

under `basedir/normal`, there are about hundred other subdirectories, but I am only interested in the abc. However, when I am calling the `DirectoryScanner.getExcludedFiles()`, I think it called slowScanner() and apparently it must have scanned all the other subdirectories, which led to a 24 hours turnaround. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `dir` of The file set to `basedir/normal/abc` then your patterns will be:

```
control/*.ins
models/bx/cells/*.l
```